# spacing virtuemart cart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Im having problems spacing out my virtuemart cart.

I was hoping someone could have a look and see what my problem could be. I know this is a very broud question but I dont know where else to turn to.

As you can see nothing is really lined up.

https://colman.net.nz/colmannew/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.cart&product_id=2&Itemid=20

You might need to add to cart and all that to actually view the shopping cart.

Any references, or help would be amazing.

Thanks,
Callum

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this off what is quite a broad question, so if it's not what you're after let me know and I'll try and answer better.

Try doing the following 2 edits, I did them using firebug and it improved the appearance of your cart dramatically:

https://colman.net.nz/colmannew/components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/onepage/icetheme_twocolumn/onepage.css - This file near line 55 change the following:

```
width: 90%;
```

to:

```
width: 20%;
```

This accompanied with giving your table TD elements the following:

```
valign="middle"
```

and

```
style="padding:5px 0;"
```

This is obviously using inline-styles as I don't wish to dictate as to where you put your CSS though in a .css file is recommended for these styles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help udjamaflip. 

Ive managed to change the width fine but I tried to add the valign and style but nothing. i have edited to this file here

colman.net.nz/colmannew/templates/adventure/css/default.css

where it says td,div {font-size:100%} although I have now deleted the valign and style.

Comment: Does it work if you place the valign/style inline into the html?

Comment: no unfortunatly. and since i have tables throughout the website for some pages if i muck around with the TD elements then the other pages muck up aswell. I got it looking OK with your help its just the price column thats causing me grief.